# AngularJs audio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

How do I acknowledge when an audio ends in angular js? I have attached my code. Anyone plz help me.

```
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,ngAudio,$document)
    {
        $scope.src="aud.mp3";
        $scope.play=false;
        $scope.play=function()
        {
            $scope.audio = ngAudio.load('aud.mp3');
            $scope.audio.play();
        }
        $scope.stop=function()
        {
            $scope.audio = ngAudio.load('aud.mp3');
            $scope.audio.pause();
        }
         $document[0].addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        var doucmentHidden = document.hidden;
        if (doucmentHidden)
            $scope.audio.pause();
        else
            $scope.audio.play();
        }, false);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some researches, I didn't find a listener that can tell you when the Aduio ends, but I found two attributes that can give you some useful states :

```
$scope.audio.paused
```

or

```
$scope.audio.canPlay
```

both of them return booleans, so what you need to do, is to define a function like this :

```
function listen(audio, callBack) { 
    if(audio.paused) {
         callBack();
    } else {
         setTimeout(listen);
    }
}
```

The problem with this function is that you need to call it everytime you call the `.play()` method

```
$scope.audio.play();
listen($scope.audio, function () { 
    console.log("ended !!");
});
```

Note that this is not a good solution, one of the good solutions is to use the native `Audio` constructor:

```
$scope.audio = new Audio("aud.mp3");
$scope.audio.onended = function () { 
    console.log("ended !! ");
}
$scope.audio.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to listen to the ended event unless you edit the module by yourself, I had to edit that module to allow event listener `angular.audio.js Line 240`

```
    cleverAudioFindingService.find(id)
        .then(function(nativeAudio) {
            audio = nativeAudio;
            audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
                audioObject.canPlay = true;
            });
             /*-----*/
            audio.addEventListener('ended',function(){
                alert('ended');
            });
             /*-----*/
        }, function(error) {
            audioObject.error = true;
            console.warn(error);
        });
```

Since this is not a good practice, I alternatively used [this angular-player](http://blog.jetboystudio.com/articles/angular-music-player/)